# Bot is not defined or Client.channel.get is not a funtion... Why?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a little problem. I want to create an `announcement` command for my Discord bot. I found a "reffer code" in a topic but when I use it, the debug console send me "bot is not defined" or when I replace bot by Client "Client.channels.get" is not a function.. Can you explain me what is wrong?

```js
const msg = message.content;
const announceChannel = bot.channels.get("778027412435763233");

if (cmd === '${prefix}announce') {
   let announceEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
   .setTitle(":flag_jp: **Annonce** :flag_jp:")
   .setDescription(msg)
   .setColor("#ff0000");

   return announceChannel.send(announceEmbed);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please provide the code in text next time you're trying to get support on here, it's a lot better for us when trying to provide support.

With v12 coming along, the channel objects you're getting must be cached, and it can simply be done using the function:

```
bot.channels.cache.get('channel id here');
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I tried to replace it by bot.channels.cache.get('channel id here'); and it doesn't work... That send me in Debug console " Uncaught ReferenceError: bot is not defined".. I need to install something with the terminal ?   --------------- const msg = message.content; 
const announceChannel = bot.channels.cache.get("778027412435763233");

if(cmd === `${prefix}announce`){
    let announceEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(":flag_jp: **Annonce** :flag_jp:")
    .setDescription(msg)
    .setColor("#ff0000");

    return announceChannel.send(announceEmbed);
}

Comment: How is `bot` defined?
It should be defined as `const bot = new Discord.Client()`

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using `Client.login`, so I have to assume that `Client` is your bot. Then you can simply do:

```js
let announceChannel = Client.channels.cache.get('Channel ID Here');
```

You are using `RichEmbed` as well, which means wether you are using an outdated version of discord.js or you don't know that it is `MessageEmbed` in discord.js v12. Type `npm i discord.js@latest` in your terminal (or whereever you install packages for your bot). Then replace `RichEmbed()` with `MessageEmbed()` and use my first example for the channel.